# Find Amount of Values in an Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, numbers

### Problem

So, this is pretty straight forward; I am making a program that asks for some information (favorite numbers), and you separate the numbers by spaces, and that is sent to an `array`. Then, I need to find how many `value`s are in the `array`.

### Example

```
print "What is your favorite number? (if you have more than one, seperate by spaces)"
favoriteNumbersUnformat = gets.chomp
favoriteNumbers = favoriteNumbersUnformat.split(' ').map(&:to_i)
```

### Explanation & End

So, that block of code above will take some numbers, and send them to an `array` with it adding a new `value` for each space e.g `2 8 21` → `[2, 8, 21]`. That works just dandy but I want some way to have the program find how many `value`s are in the array. That way, I could find out how many favorite numbers they have (for example).

I imagine this is a pretty simple problem and I thought something like this would have been asked before on Stackoverflow but I put in my title and I found nothing, over and over again. Even when I altered it a dozen times, it still didn't come up with what I want.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Ruby convention is to use [snake-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for names of variables and methods (e.g., `favorite_numbers`). You are under no obligation to adhere to that convention but you'll find that 99+% of Rubiests do. Also, `.split` without an argument is often used, as it is equivalent to `split(/\s+)`; that is, split on one or more whitespace characters.

Comment: `arr.size` or `arr.length`, self-explanatory I hope. It would probably be worth following a tutorial where these sorts of things are covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
favoriteNumbers.count
```

is the method you are looking for!